# catalog:images:resize not working in CLI in 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, product-images, cli, magento2.3.4, image-resize

We just upgraded our dev site from 2.3.3 to 2.3.4 and I'm trying to run the `bin/magento catalog:images:resize` command in CLI in hopes that it will fix some image styling issues I'm trying to resolve (removing white space from the border of a landscape image so it lines up with the product text on our product page).

However, when I run this command in CLI, I'm getting the following error message: `Cannot resize images - product images not found`

I can't seem to find any documentation on this error online. Anyone have any ideas on where to look for a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not dealt with this issue myself, and resize is working fine on our M234 stores.

Although the catalog resize function works by pulling the image paths from the database, so it seems like either a DB connection / data issue.

Below I've linked where the error is thrown, having a deeper look into the `getCountUsedProductImages` method and running equivalent sql queries should provide more details on what the actual issue is.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/MediaStorage/Service/ImageResize.php#L183

Comment: Thank you, Sam! This helped...it looks like one of our media gallery tables (catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value) was dropped somewhere in the upgrade process, which is why we're getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

OMG thank you Sam,lost hours on this hours.Resizer will not work with products set to not visible individually. Path for imageresizer is in vendor/magento/module-media-storage/Service

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value B WHERE A.value_id=B.value_id)
```